# Is there a collection with both Contains and IndexOf methods that are faster than a List?

Tags: c#, collections

I'm building a serialization system which puts a table of types at the start of the file so that each field being serialized can simply store the index of its type before the actual data (instead of storing the full type name with every field). To do this I need to:

1. If not Contains then Add: to build a collection of System.Types while ensuring that every element is unique.
2. IndexOf: to get the index of a field's type in that collection to Serialize before the field.

---

- Dictionary is good for the first objective, but doesn't have IndexOf.
- List can do both, but would be really inefficnent. O(N^2) I believe?

Does such a collection exist?

Comment: Why not implementing your own dictionary with a custom indexof method? Which access another dictionary with the element as your key and the index as the value. `Dictionary<YourClass, int>`

Comment: Well, you're just taking the problem the wrong way. The index here is your value, not your key. A `Dictionary<Type, int>` should do the job (and when deserializing, you instead create a `Dictionary<int, Type>` to do the inverse job)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing already exists, it's called... A dictionary. You simply need to take your problem the other way: the index is your value, not your key.

Your method could look like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, int> serializationTable = new Dictionary<Type, int>();

public int GetSerializationIndex(Type type)
{
    int index;

    if (!this.serializationTable.TryGetValue(type, out index))
    {
        index = this.serializationTable.Count;
        this.serializationTable.Add(type, index);
    }

    return index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that got me onto the right track. I can't actually set the index when adding types because the order will change. Instead I add everything at index 0 while building the table, then when I write each type into the stream I set its index so that when each field looks up its type index it gets the actual order that was written to the stream. Then I can just deserialize the types into a List at the other side.